# adjoint operator of the partial trace map

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, trace, adjoint-operators, trace-map

Could someone explain to me, what is the adjoint map of the partial trace map the (tensored with the identity map), or why does the following equality hold? $Tr(C_A\cdot Tr_{B} D_{AB})=Tr((C_A\otimes Id_B)\cdot D_{AB})$? I think I can see it intuitively from wikipedia, but mathematically can someone prove it?

Answer (score 3):

If you write $D=\sum_j X_j\otimes Y_j$, with $X_j\in A$, $Y_j\in B$, then
$$
\text{Tr}_B(D)=\sum_j\text{Tr}(Y_j)X_j,
$$
and
$$
\text{Tr}(C\cdot\text{Tr}(D))=\text{Tr}(\sum_j \text{Tr}(Y_j)CX_j)=\sum_j\text{Tr}(CX_j)\text{Tr}(Y_j).
$$
Also,
$$
\text{Tr}((C\otimes I)D)=\text{Tr}(\sum_j CX_j\otimes Y_j)=\sum_j\text{Tr}(CX_j)\text{Tr}(Y_j).
$$

Comment: So, why do we know that we can write D in that way split into two systems? Is that the Schmidt/Spectral decomposition?

Comment: It is the definition of a tensor product. What is a tensor product for you?

Comment: Actually my question was, if we know D belongs to a space of $A\otimes B$, in that it lives in two registers labelled (A,B). why does it follow that it should be separable in that way?

Comment: I don't know what a "register" is. I ask again: what does $A\otimes B $ mean for you?

Comment: the usual definition of tensor product.. A lives in a space $\mathcal{C}^n$ and B lives in $\mathcal{C}^n$. So $A\otimes B$ means is a tensor product space. But in your answer, is it obvious D can be decomposed in that way?

Comment: The "usual" definition of tensor product is exactly what I'm using. I'm not sure what you mean by "lives". Here $A$ is a vector space, $B$ is a vector space, and $A\otimes B$ is a vector space; the latter is obtained as the smallest vector space that contains all elementary tensor $a\otimes b$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. As a vector space contains all sums of its elements, it follows that $A\otimes B$ is precisely the set of all $\sum_j a_j\otimes b_j$ with $a_j\in A$ and $b_j\in B$.

Comment: Is the operator $Id\otimes tr_{B}$ positive?If it is true,how to show that?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the statement that $\operatorname{Tr}_B$ is completely positive, which is turns is a restatement of the fact that $\operatorname{Tr}$ is completely positive.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but the formula you wrote above can be seen as the coordinate-free definition of the partial trace. Namely, the partial trace $tr_W$ is the unique operator, that for all $M \in V\otimes W$ and $N \in V$ fulfills that

$ tr( M_{VW} ⋅ N_{V} \otimes I_W) = tr( tr_W(M_{VW}) \cdot N_V)$.

Because $\langle A,B \rangle = tr(A^\dagger B)$ is the Hilber-Schmidt inner product, 
the partial trace can be seen as the the adjoint to the map $V \to V \otimes I$.